Health probe with errors in Azure Container App
I have an application running nodejs and redis services. The exposed port is only 3000. This application is an api that queries and stores data in a postgresql.
The services run in a single container.
My problem is that when I check the system log, I keep getting liveness, readiness and startup errors, even though I already have them configured.
So I wanted to know if anyone has had this problem and how to solve it.
I have the ingress type enabled and http type.
Another important thing to mention is that this application will be receiving approximately 150,000 requests per day.
Thanks!
This is the configuration I currently have:
Configuration of health probes
My Dockerfile
FROM node:21.4-bookworm

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y iputils-ping traceroute telnet dnsutils git nano htop redis-server && \
    npm install -g pm2 && \
    ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Santiago /etc/localtime && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN echo "user1:password" | chpasswd

RUN adduser -u 2000 user2 && \
    echo "user2:password" | chpasswd

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/CUA-Tunel

COPY . .
    
EXPOSE 3000

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

My entrypoint
#!/bin/bash

# Configuración DNS
echo search server01.domain.com > /etc/resolv.conf
echo search server02.domain.com >> /etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" >> /etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" >> /etc/resolv.conf

echo "maxclients 500000" >> /etc/redis/redis.conf

npm install

/etc/init.d/redis-server start

npx pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --no-daemon

My compose
#version: '2.0'

services:
  tunel-nodejs:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"


Adjust Probe settings increase initial delays along with ensuring that your application is ready and responsive. What if the probe time is too short? Give it a try

As I understand that you have already deployed a containerized Node.js application with Redis and PostgreSQL on your Container Apps and you are having issues with liveness, readiness, and startup probes.
Now this could be due to various reasons. I would recommend you verify if the health endpoints are working
The endpoints /healthz, /readyz, and /startupz in your Node.js application should be returning OK when accessed.
curl https://myapp.salmonsky-00bc5d91.eastus.azurecontainerapps.io/healthz
curl https://myapp.salmonsky-00bc5d91.eastus.azurecontainerapps.io/readyz
curl https://myapp.salmonsky-00bc5d91.eastus.azurecontainerapps.io/startupz


then check the logs

Since your application is handling 150,000 requests per day, consider scaling
az containerapp update \
  --name myapp \
  --resource-group arkorg \
  --min-replicas 2 \
  --max-replicas 10

check if your nodejs app is configured correctly for the probes
index.js
const express = require('express');
const redis = require('redis');
const { Client } = require('pg');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Connect to Redis
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
  host: process.env.REDIS_HOST || 'localhost',
  port: 6379
});

redisClient.on('error', (err) => console.error('Redis Client Error', err));

// Connect to PostgreSQL
const pgClient = new Client({
  user: process.env.PGUSER || 'psqladminun',
  host: process.env.PGHOST || 'localhost',
  database: process.env.PGDATABASE || 'postgres',
  password: process.env.PGPASSWORD || 'abcdefg',
  port: process.env.PGPORT || 5432,
});

pgClient.connect();

// Liveness Probe
app.get('/healthz', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('OK');
});

// Readiness Probe
app.get('/readyz', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('Ready');
});

// Startup Probe
app.get('/startupz', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('Started');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}`);
});

package.json
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node.js app with Redis and PostgreSQL",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "pg": "^8.6.0",
    "redis": "^3.1.2"
  }
}

You can also do it from azure portal

Reference-
Configure health probes in azure container apps
Verify health probes configuration
